# Android studio SDK Failure : How to solve this issue?

Tags: android-studio

I tried many times Import-android studio project in my windows-7 pc. But i failed. I searched my problem then another problem comes around. I know IDE problem, but i don't know how to solve this issue.

My Question is who have installed android studio successfully. Please share your knowledge with us.

Android studio SDK Failure : How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering problems with android studio, just uninstall android studio and then reinstall it. To be sure to have a clean install, reinstall the whole program, including the IDE and the sdk. You will then open your existing projects in android studio and retrieve it normally.

Follow this tutorial if you still have problems, it's very detailled :https://s3.amazonaws.com/content.udacity-data.com/course/ud853/Android+Studio+Setup+Guide+for+Windows+(6).pdf